# How to go to specific page number of the paginator from the view in DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i have a path like this:
`path('comments/', CommentList.as_view(), name='comment-view'),` 
i want that when i fetch that URL with the parameter: ?comment-id=37  for example, then Django should give the page that contains that comment.
i use generic view and I'm able to calculate the page number that contains that comment like this:

```
 class CommentList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
 permission_classes = [permissions.AllowAny]
 queryset = Comment.objects.all()
 serializer_class = CommentSerializer
 def get_queryset(self):
     if 'comment_id' in self.request.GET:
 
         comment_id = self.request.GET.get('comment_id')
         thread_id = self.request.GET.get('thread')
         num_preceeding_results = Comment.objects.filter(thread=thread_id,id__lt=comment_id).count()
         page = num_preceeding_results // page_size + 1
         offset = (page - 1) * 10
    return Comment.objects.filter(thread=self.request.GET.get('thread'))
```

now all i need is to return the desired page. i tried reverse and reverse lazy but they didn't work. so any suggestion please?

i tried:
return reverse('comment-view') + f'?thread={thread_id}&offset={offset}'

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/pagination/

Comment: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/

Comment: @Andrew the filtering page doesn't have anything related to pagination, and the pagination page doesn't include changing page number, but just the limit. and note that i want to change the page number just under a condition, so if you can help me with a specific answer

Comment: `thread_id = self.request.GET.get('thread')`.  `Comment.objects.filter(`, ....

Comment: First step is to read the docs that handle your exact case, perhaps?  You want to return a desired page, but you use offset?  why not page number pagination.  Dunno, maybe read the docs on pagination